# How to insert array in single field

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store ids in database like this `1,2,3,4,5` in one field from a while loop.
how can i do this.

I am trying this way.

```
$array = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$array[] = array($row['id']);
}

$query = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO temp (temp) VALUES('$array')");
print_r($array);
```

This is showing error `Array to string conversion` and value as `Array` is inserted in database.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use [json_encode](http://uk.php.net/json_encode) ? :)

Comment: I recommend using `serialize($array)` to convert into string, and then `unserialize($string)` to transform it back into an array.

Comment: I recommend normalising the database - SO is filled with questions asking how to deal with the problems created by storing arrays like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrays = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arrays[] = $row['id'];
}
$arr_str  = implode(",", $arrays);
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO temp (temp) VALUES('$arr_str')");
//print_r($array);
```

Detailed information about implode can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: @MihaiIorga: with all due respect, have you read the question? Its clearly mentioned there that "I want to store ids in database like this 1,2,3,4,5 in one...". I know, that what i have suggested is not good code in all scenarios but here he has clearly stated what is needed.

Comment: This answer is the third duplicate. -1

Comment: @GreenRover: when i wrote this answer, there was none on the page. When i posted and page loaded, i saw there were other answers too. You can find out by time posted. And, i am not repo-hungry. You can down-vote or do anything you like. Please dont mind.

Comment: @TallboY: answer that i have specified here is for the scenario OP specified in condition. This may not work in all scenarios. You have array within array, so you might have to apply different logic.

Comment: got it working like `$array[] = $row['id'];`, insted if `$array[] = array($row['id']);`

Answer (score 4):

Create another table and insert 5 rows into it.

```
entity_id | ids
1             1
1             2
1             3
1             4
1             5
```

that's the only proper way of doing such things

However, if it's really a temp table, there is probably a way to avoid these inserts at all.

Comment: Isn't it a bit too much to use another table just to store an array of plain values?

Comment: This is the correct way +1. Everything else shows that someone dont understand how to use sql. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: i completely agree that this is the correct way, but has OP not mentioned in his question itselt what he wants? Anyways...

Answer (score 3):

You can use either **serialize** or **json_encode**:

```
$data = serialize($array);
// ...or...
$data = json_encode($array);
```

If the array just contains plain numbers you can also use **implode**:

```
$data = implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: There are only realy less reasons why to do this. Sometimes you have big data blocks. The you should use serialize or json_encode. If implode is possible ever use a socond table!

Comment: Then you should use one of the first two methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `implode()` function:

```
$to_insert = implode(',', $array);
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO temp (temp) VALUES('$to_insert')");
```

Comment: Did you read the question? He clearly indicates the contents of his array (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5), so this solution is still valid. Of course, if there were strings, an alternate solution would be required...

Comment: At least you're big enough to accept that, unlike most people on the Internet these days... :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO temp (temp) VALUES(".join(',', $array).")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ids = join(',',$array);
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO temp (temp) VALUES('$ids')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use **implode** function before insert into database :-

Here is a example :-

```
 $array = array(1,2,3);
 $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

 echo $comma_separated;
```

Output :-

```
  1,2,3
```

In your case :-

```
    $array = array();

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array[] = array($row['id']);
    }
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO temp (temp) VALUES('$comma_separated')");
    print_r($array);
```

Comment: If comma separated value in your array then serialize should be better

Comment: I have sent above example because you have mentioned in your question you need output like 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 0):

Set the field type varchar(255) and do this with php

```
$array = array();
$value = serialize($array);

$query = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO temp (temp) VALUES('$value')");
print_r($array);
```

To retrieve the value you should unserialize the column

```
$data = unserialize($result['temp']);
```

Here result is associative array. $data is an array you dont have to implode or explode or json_encode or json_decode